# NumericTextBox and MaskedTextBox Kendo UI for Angular2

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I was waiting for Kendo UI for Angular2 RC.0 for NumericTextBox and MaskedTextBox, but it was not released in RC 0. What's the plan for these controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These components were released yesterday. The RC.0 release is not yet announced however.

- NumericTextBox - http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/numerictextbox/
- MaskedTextBox - http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/maskedtextbox/